# Convert print followed by comma into writelines in python

Tags: python, string, printing

I have a script that works right now and prints the output on the python shell window. I want to write these lines into a file and not the shell.

```
for k in keys:
    print '%s' % (d[k]),
print ""
```

I did this because the comma will print as a single line (all the keys into a single line) and then read the second line and print that... But I want **it written into a file** the **same** way that it **prints into the console**. I tried to use .join() but I am not doing it right. I have pasted what I tried so far..

```
val_list = []
for k in keys:
  val = '%s' % d[k]
  val_list.append(val)
print ''.join(val_list)
```

This outputs all the keys as a single line, so when it goes through the for loop, it should print the first line print the keys then go to the next line print the keys, then third line and so on.. Each line is a unique set of values so I need it like that. Finally I want all the keys to be written into a  file

Comment: Is `'\n'.join(...` what you want?

Comment: I tried \n and it print out k1\n k2\n k3 so on and doe sthe same for next line. I need k1k2k3k4k5.... \n k1k2k3k4k5.... \n so on

Comment: May be i should use izip??? but I am not sure if thats right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to use `>>` as follows:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k in keys:
        print>>f, '%s' % (d[k]),
    print>>f, ""
```

Comment: Awesome!!! this worked. I dont know why I dont come up with these ideas. Even after looking at so many threads... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you want.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as f:
    val_list = []
    for k in keys:
        val = '%s' % d[k]
        val_list.append(val)
    f.write(' '.join(val_list) + '\n\n')
```

Comment: This dint work, it gave output as first line \n firstline appended with second line \n .... so on